# How to set existing connection for Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, transactions, database-connection, lumen

We are migrating a legacy application to lumen. The application uses Transactions. How to set the existing connection to eloquent to execute the SQL of the ORM in the Transaction.

The connection is handled by a custom database class and is created by `pg_connect()`. I need to set the created resource as connection for eloquent to use the transactions and other connection settings which are created in the legacy code.

The setConnection method of the model only accept a string for the configuration of database connection. The resource could not be passed.

How to set the manually created connection object to the ORM?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are talking about a PDO connection, you need to set a Connection Resolver on the model in question, look at this example on using `User::class`

```php
// setup
$databaseName = 'my_database_name';
$tablePrefix = '';
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=$databaseName", 'root', '');
$container = new \Illuminate\Container\Container(); // you should use the app container, this is just a placeholder

// 1st step - we need to create a custom factory to expose the base method responsible for doing the work under the hood
$customFactory = new class($container) extends \Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory
{
    /**
     * @param PDO    $pdo
     * @param string $database
     * @param string $prefix
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Connection
     */
    public function makeConnection(PDO $pdo, $database, $prefix = '')
    {
        return $this->createConnection($pdo->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME), $pdo, $database, $prefix);
    }
};

// 2nd - we use the method that we just created to convert the PDO instance into a Laravel connection
$connection = $customFactory->makeConnection($pdo, $databaseName, $tablePrefix);

// 3rd - we need to configure our connection resolver, you can use the above method to create you own instance, or you can use the one provided by the container
$resolver = new \Illuminate\Database\ConnectionResolver();
$resolver->addConnection('custom', $connection);
$resolver->setDefaultConnection('custom');

// 4th - assign the resolver to your model 
User::setConnectionResolver($resolver);

// 5th - profit
dump(User::all());
```

Comment: I've modified my question to explain that we use a resource object as basic method to maintain the database connection. You also create a new connection form the data of the pdo. I need to set the resource because the should use the existing connection (inclusive Transaction and so on)

Comment: From what I know, eloquent only supports Postgres via PDO

Comment: My problem isn't to connect to the database. I'd like to inject the existing to connection resource to be in the same transaction scope and so on. Not to be in the same scope can cause terrible bugs.

Comment: The example above was not how to connect to the database, was how to inject the PDO connection into the ORM system, if you have a connection that is not PDO, you need to (in this case) extend `Illuminate\Database\PostgresConnection` and use the pg_* functions instead of PDO for select/updated/etc methods